# SQL to XML Formatting

Tags: sql-server, xml, formatting, format

I am attempting to join three tables for a SQL query to output as XML 
Below is my query:

```
select 
    invoices.order_no as "order",
    customerinfo.name as BillingCompanyName,
    line.item_code, 
    line.item_qty
from 
    invoices
inner join 
    customerinfo on customerinfo.cust_code = invoices.cust_code
inner join 
    line on line.order_no = invoices.order_no
where 
    invoices.custlog10 = 'f' and invoices.order_no = '332504'
for xml auto, type, elements
```

and here is the generated output

```
<invoices>
  <order>332504</order>
  <customerinfo>
    <BillingCompanyName>Two Bear Farm</BillingCompanyName>
    <line>
      <item_code>2909-B</item_code>
      <item_qty>2.000000</item_qty>
    </line>
    <line>
      <item_code>SH-DISC</item_code>
      <item_qty>1.000000</item_qty>
    </line>
  </customerinfo>
</invoices>
```

This output is for the most part right I just with to move where the `customerinfo` tag ends, like the following see in bold:

```
<invoices>
  <order>332504</order>
  <customerinfo>
    <BillingCompanyName>Two Bear Farm</BillingCompanyName>
  </customerinfo>
  <line>
      <item_code>2909-B</item_code>
      <item_qty>2.000000</item_qty>
  </line>
  <line>
      <item_code>SH-DISC</item_code>
      <item_qty>1.000000</item_qty>
  </line>
</invoices>
```

This code is meant to feed into a third party module to read sales orders.

I am new to SQL output as XML and any help to resolve this formatting issue would be fantastic!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is by correlated queries with explicit path as you can take more control over the format:

```
select 
    invoices.order_no as "order",

    (select customerinfo.name as 'BillingCompanyName'
     from customerinfo where 
     customerinfo.cust_code=invoices.cust_code
    for xml path('customerinfo'), type, elements
    ),

    (select line.item_code, line.item_qty
     from line where line.order_no = invoices.order_no
     for xml path('line'), type, elements)
from 
    invoices
where 
    invoices.custlog10 = 'f' and invoices.order_no = '332504'
for xml path('invoices')
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f2128/1)